# Expected Double value to display two zeros after precision value

Tags: java

I have a scenario where we need to display two zeros i.e 00 after the precision for double value. But unfortunately Java is not returning the second zero.

I have tried the below way but it is returning only one zero after decimal.

```
double inputvalue = 12345.00;
double d = ((BigDecimal.valueOf(inputvalue)).setScale(2,RoundingMode.UP)).doubleValue();
```

Expected output: 12345.00 but it is returning 1234.0.

Comment: Java has `NumberFormat` for this, or `String.printf()`.

Comment: i dont see any problem. your scale method is returning that you expected.

Comment: `double` doesn't have a built in format, if you want to change the way it is displayed you need to use a format to say what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a string to display the value. e.g.
`String.format( "%.2f", d)`